# Swagger (via NSwag) descriptions of fields of return types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nswag

Is it possible to make Swagger UI show the xml documentation for return models?

For example, let's say that the response model returns an object with a field called `Data`. Is it possible to make Swashbackle to expose the XML Summary for this property?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

1. Use `ActionResult<DataType>` for method's return type in controller

```
public ActionResult<DataType> GetData(int id) {
  ...
  return data;
}
```

2. Use `[ProducesResponseType(200, typeof(DataType))]` attribute. This way, you can specify not only for success return, but also for other response code.

```
[ProducesResponseType(200, typeof(DataType))]
[ProducesResponseType(400, typeof(BadRequestReturnType))]
[ProducesResponseType(500, typeof(ServerErrorReturnType))]
public IActionResult GetData(int id) {
  ...
  return data;
}
```

You can use both, i.e. use `ActionResult<DataType>` for 200, and `ProducesResponseType` for other codes.

You can refer to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0#actionresultt-type) for more info.

Comment: I don't believe this provides documentation for the fields the the return type.

Comment: @tymtam -- if you add 3-slash comments above the fields of the models, they will show up in the "models" section of your swagger doc.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I'm using NSwag, not Swashbuckle.